# slot machince not looping numbers

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a slot machine program that will have the user enter a amount of money and then display 3 words from 5 randomly generated numbers. If 3 of the words match they win 3 times the amount of money entered, if 2 words words match they win 2 times the amount and if 0 match they win nothing. When I run the program and hit yes to play again it just gives me the same match every-time. I am not sure why it is doing this.

here is what I have so far

```
Console.Write("\n\n");
Console.Write("------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("\nThis Program simulates a slot machince");
Console.Write("------------------------------------------------");
Console.Write("\n\n");                      
string answer;                       
int moneyWon = 0;


Random random = new Random();
int randomWord1 = random.Next(0, 5);
int randomWord2 = random.Next(0, 5);
int randomWord3 = random.Next(0, 5);

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount to depost into the slot machince: ");
    int moneyDeposit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                                               

    if (randomWord1 == 0 && randomWord2 == 0 && randomWord3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cherries, Cherries, Cherries");
        Console.WriteLine("3 words match. you won 3x");


        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 3;

    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Oranges, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("3 words match. you won 3x");


        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 3;

    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Plums, Plums");
        Console.WriteLine("3 words match. you won 3x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 3;

    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 3 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Bells, Bells");
        Console.WriteLine("3 words match. you won 3x");


        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 3;

    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 4 && randomWord2 == 4 && randomWord3 == 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Melons, Melons, Melons");
        Console.WriteLine("3 words match. you won 3x");


        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 3;

    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 5 && randomWord2 == 5 && randomWord3 == 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bars, Bars, Bars");
        Console.WriteLine("3 words match. you won 3x");


        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 3;

    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 0 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cherries, Oranges, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");


        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;

    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Oranges, Cherries");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 0 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Cherries, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 0 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cherries, Plums, Plums");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Plums, Cherries");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 0 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Cherries, Plums");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }

    else if (randomWord1 == 3 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Bells, Cherries");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 0 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cherries, Bells, Bells");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 3 && randomWord2 == 0 && randomWord3 == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Cherries, Bells");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 3 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Bells, Cherries");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 0 && randomWord2 == 4 && randomWord3 == 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cherries, Melons, Melons");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 4 && randomWord2 == 4 && randomWord3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Melons, Melons, Cherries");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 4 && randomWord2 == 0 && randomWord3 == 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Melons, Cherries, Melons");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 0 && randomWord2 == 5 && randomWord3 == 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cherries, Bars, Bars");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 5 && randomWord2 == 5 && randomWord3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bars, Bars, Cherries");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 5 && randomWord2 == 0 && randomWord3 == 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bars, Cherries, BarsS");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 0 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Cherries, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Oranges, Cherries");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 0 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cherries, Oranges, Cherries");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Oranges, Plums");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Plums, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Oranges, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Plums, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Oranges, Bells");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Bells, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 3 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Oranges, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }                           
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Oranges, Melons");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 4 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Melons, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 4 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Melons, Oranges, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Oranges, Bars");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 5 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Bells, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 5 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Oranges, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Plums, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Plums, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Oranges, Plums");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Plums, Bells");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Bells, Plums");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 3 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Plums, Plums");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 4 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Melons, Plums");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 4 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Melons, Plums, Plums");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Plums, Melons");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 5 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bars, Plums, Plums");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Plums, Bars");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 5 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Bars, Plums");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 3 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Bells, Cherries");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 3 && randomWord2 == 0 && randomWord3 == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Cherries, Bells");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 0 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cherries, Bells, Bells");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oranges, Bells, Bells");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 3 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Bells, Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 3 && randomWord2 == 1 && randomWord3 == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Oranges, Bells");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 1 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cherries, Bells, Bells");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 2 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plums, Bells, Bells");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 3 && randomWord2 == 3 && randomWord3 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Bells, Plums");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }
    else if (randomWord1 == 3 && randomWord2 == 2 && randomWord3 == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bells, Plums, Bells");
        Console.WriteLine("2 words match, you won 2x");

        moneyWon += moneyDeposit * 2;
    }                                                                                     
      //continue if statements                                                                                                                                                          
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No words match.You won 0");
    }

    // Display total deposit, amount won and net gain/losss to the user
    double netGain = moneyWon;
    Console.WriteLine($"Total amount depostited:{moneyDeposit} ");
    Console.WriteLine($"Total amount won:{moneyWon} ");
    Console.WriteLine($"Net gain/loss total:{netGain} ");

    //Ask the user if they want to play again
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again yes/no: ");
    answer = Console.ReadLine();
    if(answer != "Yes" || answer != "yes" || answer != "No" || answer != "no")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input try again");
    }

} while (answer == "Yes" || answer == "yes");
```

Comment: You only ever set the three random numbers once, outside the loop. Everything that happens multiple times must go *inside* the loop.

Comment: Please never ever never write code like this in real life. `C#` is primarily an object oriented language and you need to start thinking about how to model a game like this in terms of its state (classes & data) and how it changes (methods & events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same unknown values for each iteration of the loop.
You need to generate the random numbers within the loop:

```cs
Random random = new Random();
do
{
   int randomWord1 = random.Next(0, 5);
   int randomWord2 = random.Next(0, 5);
   int randomWord3 = random.Next(0, 5);
   //...
```

Comment: Create the new Random outside the do loop.   There is no reason to construct the new Random for each run.  In theory you will get better random results doing it my way.  The difference between my code and current code will be very small.

Comment: @jdweng is correct. It is important to create only one Random, and use that same Random object every time through the loop.

Comment: My college probability teach said following 1) It depends on how random the generator is.  If you have a perfect random generator that initialize it once 2) The teacher infamous question : "If you have a perfectly random deck of cards and shuffled the deck one more time, do you get a deck that is more or less random"?  Putting the random constructor inside the do loop is equivalent to shuffling the deck one more time.